# How to add new row to unbound devexpress GridControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have create grid controle and in designer I add 4 columns(BS, Repere, Profil, Quantity),and I want to add new row in click of button, so I use this code:

```
gridView2.AddNewRow();    
                    gridView2.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView2.Columns["BS"], rowGridView1["BS"]);
                    gridView2.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView2.Columns["Repere"], rowGridView1["Repère"]);
                    gridView2.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView2.Columns["Profil"], rowGridView1["Profil"]);
                    gridView2.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView2.Columns["Quantity"], quantity.EditValue);
```

but when I run the code nothing happend,my grid control not binding to any type of data ,How do I solve this problem? , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a class that will hold the data for a single Row

```
class GridRow 
{
   public string BS { get; set;}
   public string Repere { get; set; }
   public string Profil { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

then bind the grid's DataSource property to a list of rows like this

```
this.gridRows = new List<GridRow>();
this.grid.DataSource = this.gridRows;
```

then to add a new row do this

```
this.gridRows.Add(new GridRow() { BS = "some value", Repare = "Some value", Quantity = 10});
this.gridView1.RefreshData();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me I appreciate it so much